# How to set a global secret key to handle sessions in flask

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-session

I have a flask application with several blueprints names as `auth,admin,user`
I am having one secret key in `view.py` of auth blueprint.

How to make this as a global key so that I can use it everywhere in the app

I set `secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'` in run.py file. But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new file with something like:

```
# config.py
import os
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'
```

And then in your flask `__init__.py` file import it:

```
from config import Config
# And after the flask app instanciation you do
flask_app_instance.config.from_object(Config)
```

This way you will only need to call it by `flask_app_instance.config["SECRET_KEY"]`

EDIT: well OP found the solution, leaving this here anyway

EDIT2:

If you are planing to deploy your whatever you're doing you should consider not writing the secret_key inside your script and do something like this instead:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'some secret key here'
```

This will take grab the secret key from a env var (called SECRET_KEY) from the machine the server is on

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. I forgot to `import session` to the views.

When I imported `session`, problem was solved